# Macbook Pro Late 2011 13" Display Issue

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I'm having a weird issue with the built-in display on a Macbook Pro Late 2011 13".

As the lid is opened, the display usually activates normally at its threshold for turning on. Everything works fine. But if the lid is then opened all the way, the display dies.

If the lid is closed and opened again just until the display starts, then VERY slowly opened (like, a couple mm per minute) I can sometimes get the lid almost completely open while keeping the display alive. If it stays on, the display keeps running with no problems.

Does anyone have an idea where to start with an issue like this? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is some problem with the connecting wires for the display. If you're okay how things are, then you can just leave things be. A repair would probably cost several hundred dollars.

I have the same model Mac and also have display issues. When it was almost one year old, I noticed that the display would often go wonky (not turn off but look all weird like a light show), often if I were to open it all the way, if I recall. (So some problem with the internal wiring, probably different wires than yours though.) This was mainly a problem when I took it to class and was more prone to open the display all the way. So I quickly bought an extended warranty as someone from Apple predicted that my display issue would get worse and require a repair. But the issue never got worse, and I was always fine the way it was. I've been using this laptop for almost five years (still snappy!), and only very rarely do I experience this problem again, and the problem goes away by closing the lid and opening it more normally.